# Function DateDiff is not working in c#.net

Tags: c#

I am creating simples days calculation system using C#. I attached code and screen shot below. If I select the date from date and to date we need to calculate days between `from date to to date` to display on label control.

[image]

This is the code I tried:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateTimePicker1.Value.Date, DateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
}
```

`DateDiff` is not working

Comment: DateAndTime? which language is this?

Comment: DateDiff() works just fine, return type is long.  The screen-shot shows that you forgot to assign the label's Text property.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani - the language is C# but that library is from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you can get total days between two dates.

```
DateTime date1 = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
DateTime date2 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
int daysDiff = ((TimeSpan) (date2 - date1)).Days;
```

in short:

```
int daysDiff = ((TimeSpan) (DateTimePicker2.Value.Date- DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)).Days;
```

Answer (score 1):

To Calculate the Difference of two Dates:

```
double Days = (DateTimePicker2.Value.Date - DateTimePicker1.Value.Date).TotalDays;
```

Comment: a dubious use of `var` . TotalDays is a `double`, that may or may not fit the bill here.